# parentView property is not set in child view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

can someone please explain why this simple example from the Ember.Handlebars.helpers Class API documentation does not work for me??

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js"></script>
  <script>
    aView = Ember.View.create({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{#view}} aview: my parent:{{parentView.elementId}} {{/view}}")
    });

    aView.appendTo('body');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this just outputs:

```
aview: my parent:
```

without any elementId. In other code I have played with parentView is undefined ??

Comment: `view.parentView` should work

Comment: thanks, that works. Perhaps you can give me a clue how to solve the next piece of my puzzle .. how to access the parentView from an event handler?

Comment: Where are you handling the event?

Comment: I will post my code in another question

Comment: Don't. Just update the current question

Comment: ah.. didn't realise I could do that. already posted it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on my comments.

From within a view template in Handlebars, properties defined in a `View` class implementation (or generic, auto-generated view class) can be accessed through `view.propertyName`. Since `parentView` is a property of the current view, one should do something similar to the following:

```
{{#view}} 
    aview: my parent:{{view.parentView.elementId}} 
{{/view}}
```